# Why is "viva" pronounced `/ˈvaɪ.və/` in the academic sense?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

Usually, (and intuitively), the word is pronounced `/ˈviː.və/` or `/ˈviː.vɑ/`

However, I recently learned that in the academic context, the same term is pronounced
`/ˈvaɪ.və/`. Why is this the case, and what is its etymology?

Comment: It seems possible that this is because the borrowings of the 2 meanings occurred separately near the beginning and end of the Great Vowel Shift. "viva voce" dates back to 1565 but "viva" meaning long live only to 1640s http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/viva%20voce?s=t http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/viva . However I can't back this up with knowledge, so I'll leave that to others to answer.

Comment: You'll hear both pronunciations in UK academia, though I've never heard /ˈvaɪ.və/ in the full (but rare) *viva voce*.

Answer (score 3):

*"viva"* meaning **"long live" is borrowed from Italian or Spanish**, and approximates the pronunciation of the source languages. (IIRC, the Vauxhall Viva car had the same pronunciation, though I don't have a source for that.)

However, *"viva"*, short for *"viva voce"*, meaning **"oral examination", is borrowed from Mediaeval Latin**. Pronunciation rules for Mediaeval Latin words are not the same as those for modern Italian and Spanish, though I don't know when or why the long 'i' prevaled for this sense.

Source: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/viva

Comment: @MarchHo please don't accept this answer unless your problem is fully solved: it is worth waiting for a more complete answer from someone more knowledgeable. " A question with an accepted answer isn't as likely to receive further attention as one without an accepted answer." Also: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers